# How to add a day to current date in Ubuntu shell?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

On MacOSX you can do this to get tomorrow's date, but the `-v` option is not available in Ubuntu shell. What's the equivalent shell command in Ubuntu? `man date` didn't tell me anything.

```
$ date -v+1d +%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: My `man date` tells me all about the `-d`/`--date` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu

```
$ date --date="tomorrow" +%F
```